# Can you clone an OpenShift application repo via HTTPS instead of SSH?

Tags: git, openshift

I have created an application on OpenShift via RHC, but the cloning step fails, because I am behind a firewall, so I cannot access the server directly via SSH. I would, however, be able to access the repository via HTTPS, but I don't see that option available.

Does OpenShift even support accessing the application repositories via HTTPS?

Comment: Git is usually able to clone repos through https see [this](http://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository)

Answer (score 1):

OpenShift does not currently allow the cloning of applications over https.  It only supports ssh at this time.